# Python/Tkinter: Use button to control for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `for` loop that is meant to run through a list, display some items in tkinter, wait for a button to be pushed, and then store some `Entry` and `Checkbutton` data. The code below is a MRE of the basics of what I'm trying to do. In the case below, when the `Button` is hit, I want to return to the `loop_function` and gather the variables from the `button_function`.

I thought perhaps using something like `lambda: continue` or `lambda: return` might bring it back to the first function, but those throw errors.

Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *

class TestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.f = Frame(self.parent)
        self.f.pack()

        (Button(self.f, text='Start', 
            command = self.loop_function)
            .grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10))

    def loop_function(self):
        name_list = ['Luke', 'Han', 'Leia', 'Chewie']

        for n in name_list:
            self.button_function(n)
            force_user = self.fu.get()
            side = self.sd.get()
            print(n, force_user, side)

    def button_function(self, n):
        self.fu = IntVar(value=1)
        self.sd = StringVar(value='rebel')

        self.fu_e = Checkbutton(self.f, variable=self.fu)
        self.sd_e = Entry(self.f, textvariable=self.sd)

        col = 0
        lbl_list = ['Name', 'Force User?', 'Side']
        for l in lbl_list:
            (Label(self.f, text=l, width=11, anchor=W)
                .grid(column=col, row=0, padx=10, pady=10))
            col += 1

        (Label(self.f, text=n, width=11, anchor=W)
            .grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5))
        self.fu_e.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.sd_e.grid(column=2, row=1)
        (Button(self.f, text='Save', 
            command = lambda: print('WAIT HERE!!'))
            .grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    ui = TestClass(root)
    ui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `lambda: return` is nonsense, because `func = lambda: something` <=> `def func(): return something`

Comment: And `lambda: continue` <=> `def func(): return continue`.

Comment: Thanks I know. As stated above.

Comment: that's good :) I only explained why.

Comment: It might be me, but your code makes no sense to me. I think you should read up on the event-driven nature of GUI applications.

Comment: @RolandSmith I realize it is a silly example. In the bigger code, the number of "names" is variable and I need to collect info about each from the user. I boiled it down to make it MRE.

Comment: Well, your `loop_function` is only called from `__init__`. So it will be *finished* before the `mainloop` starts. So there is litterally *nothing to return to* from a callback. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @RolandSmith yeah maybe I'm struggling to make a MRE that actually works and demonstrates the problem. I made a small edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code does what you want to do.
After clicking on the button *Start* the user gets a dialog where she can enter properties of the first user *Luke*. By clicking on the button *Save* the entered data is stored in some way. Then the properties of the next user (*Han*) can be edited.

A for loop is not the correct approach here. Instead we want to listen for the click events of the start and save buttons. In my solution, when the user clicks *Start*, the event handler `pick_next_player` is being called. This method always picks the `next` element from an iterator that I wrapped around `name_list`. Then the GUI elements are being rendered with your `button_function`.

The event handler `save_action` listens to the click event of the *Save* button. It collects the values that the user entered, stores it into `self.results` and displays the next player by calling `pick_next_player`.

When the last player has been saved, this script just prints a line 'finished ...' to the console. I assume you are going to stop the script or close the dialog there. But this is of course up to you.

```py
from tkinter import *


class TestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.f = Frame(self.parent)
        self.f.pack()

        (
            Button(self.f, text='Start', command=self.pick_next_player)
                .grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        )

        self.name_list = ['Luke', 'Han', 'Leia', 'Chewie']
        self.name_iter = iter(self.name_list)
        self.results = []
        self.current_name = None

    def pick_next_player(self):
        try:
            self.current_name = next(self.name_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            print(f"finished: {self.results}")
            return

        self.button_function()

    def button_function(self):
        self.fu = IntVar(value=1)
        self.sd = StringVar(value='rebel')

        self.fu_e = Checkbutton(self.f, variable=self.fu)
        self.sd_e = Entry(self.f, textvariable=self.sd)

        col = 0
        lbl_list = ['Name', 'Force User?', 'Side']
        for l in lbl_list:
            (Label(self.f, text=l, width=11, anchor=W)
             .grid(column=col, row=0, padx=10, pady=10))
            col += 1

        (
            Label(self.f, text=self.current_name, width=11, anchor=W)
                .grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5)
        )
        self.fu_e.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.sd_e.grid(column=2, row=1)
        (
            Button(self.f, text='Save', command=self.save_action)
                .grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        )

    def save_action(self):
        force_user = self.fu.get()
        side = self.sd.get()
        print(f"saving {self.current_name}, {force_user}, {side}")
        self.results.append({'name': self.current_name, 'force': force_user, 'faction': side})
        self.pick_next_player()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    ui = TestClass(root)
    ui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes! This does what I want, and uses some methods I haven't used before. Thank you so much!